# Custom keyboard for react native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to implement a custom keyboard with react native. Can anyone provide me with any good packages or guide me in the right direction.

Comment: I have implemented a custom keyboard for my application too. You can view the source code [here](https://github.com/iamrohitagg/react-native-keyboard-android-ios). Please raise an issue or add comments here if you face any problem.

Comment: @RohitAggarwal What you did isn't a custom keyboard.  There's no input method service in there.  It won't work with any other app on the phone.  What you did is a fake keyboard.

Comment: @GabeSechan the keyboard I created would work for TextInput provided by `react-native`. You just have to call `hideKeyboard` method I created on focus of textniput.

Comment: @RohitAggarwal A custom keyboard works for any app on the phone, just by being installed on the device.  Yours isn't one.  It's a keyboard view, and a limited one at that.  Calling it a custom keyboard is just wrong.  What you're doing is faking a keyboard.  Which may be good enough for some usecases, but it's not an actual keyboard, and it won't work with the normal keyboard framework of the OS.  Not even for simple things, like showing the right language for the locale of the device.

Answer (score 2):

That's not going to work.  There's several problems with this.

1)You need to have an InputMethodService.  That means at best you could write a native app that has a ReactNative view.

2)Several of the IMS functions need to return a synchronous value.  ReatNative works by running Javascript asynchronously on its own thread.  There is no way to make this work.

3)Unless all your logic is in the native code, you'd need to be able to call react native when calls are made to the IMS.  But that isn't possible in React Native as of last time I looked-  RN can call out to native code, but there's no way to pass a function call through to react native.

The absolute  best you could do is an RN view and all the logic in native code.  Which would be painful and harder to do than pure native.

Then on top of all this-  performance raises its head.  Keyboard apps need to launch and display *quickly*, and preferably use as little memory and CPU as possible.  Launch times and resource usage of RN apps are very high.  It's a bad fit even if it was possible.